# How could I demonstrate this convergence?

Tags: logarithms, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I'm currently trying to demonstrate a method that I've seen that looks promising to extend tetration, but that's not directly the topic of this question.
This question is part of the method, so part of the demonstration I need to do.

$f(x)=\log_{a}{(x+1)}$

I need to demonstrate that the infinite iteration of $f(x)$ for any $x≥0$ converges to 0 if and only if $a≥e$

$f(f(f(...x)))=0, ~\forall{x≥0}$
(If $a≥e$)

Through some tests, intuition and other factors I'm almost 100% sure this is correct, but to be mathematically rigorous I need to demonstrate it.
I have a feeling that using fixed points could be a good way to demonstrate it, but I'm not 100% sure.
If you have anything to say, feel free to answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I think the question is unclear, as it is written. Are you asking whether 
$$
(\forall x \in \mathbf{C}, \lim\nolimits_{n\to \infty} f^n(x)=0) \Longleftrightarrow a\ge e \,\,\,\,? 
$$

Comment: Well I guess, I know this limit can only be true if a is greater or equal to e, I'm just trying to demonstrate it but technically you're right

Comment: Pierre, so, did I understand correctly your question? Also for $x=-1$?

Comment: Well,  yes. Demonstrating it converges to 0 for any values of x if a>=e. If it's too hard to demonstrate for $\mathbb{C} $,  well at leat doing it for 0 and positive real numbers

Comment: Pierre, as it is written, it is false simply because the (complex) logarithm of $0$ is undefined.. Maybe you want to modify your $\mathbf{C}$ with $\mathbf{C}\setminus \{-1\}$?

Comment: The only things which is complex here is x, not n. Technically there's no complex log here, but you're right. Btw I also restricted (if it's to hard for the complex) x to be positive or equal to 0 so we don't need to say that it's forbidden to put -1 for x.

Comment: Ehm, where did you read $n$? I was meaning $\log_a(0)$; anyway, you should say clearly: 

1. What is the argument of log, whether it is complex or real variable

2. In both cases, the precise equivalence that you would like to prove

(And, in particular, everything has to be well defined, whatever is the case..)

Comment: When x=0, since it's $\log_{a}{(x+1)}$ it equals $\log_{a}{(1)} = 0$ if a ≠ 1 or 0.

Comment: Also here the argument of log is all complex numbers except -1, but if the convergence is only proven for real arguments greater or equal to 0 I'm fine with it.

Comment: What about $x = a^{-1}-1$? Then $f(x) = -1$ so $f(f(x))$ is no defined.

Comment: Well you're right. I guess I'll restrict $x$ as being a real numbers larger or equal to 0.(since $x^{-1}-1$ is negative for all $x>1$